# ndb aysnc "yield next" to consume get_multi_async

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Is there a builtin or canonical way to consume the first and all successive results for a `ndb.get_multi_async` call in the order of their completion ?

I would expect, and this illustrates, it along the lines of:

```
def yield_next(futures):
   while futures:
     yield ndb.Future.wait_any(futures)
     # We have to remove the yielded future from the futures.
     # How do we know which future was removed?
     # ... futures.remove(???)

for model in yield_next(ndb.get_multi_async(keys)):
   ...
```

One way to remove the future consumed is to check `futures` to see whether it is done.
There is a race condition inherent: If any futures complete simultaneously or in any case before the `remove` call, multiple elements of `futures` may be *done*. I am otherwise not aware of a reliable way to determine which future was consumed.

One would expect that this is quite a common pattern, but I have not seen it resolved. Looking through `ndb/tasklets.py` there seem to be some exotic (read: undocumented) possibilities like `ReducingFuture` or `MultiFuture`, but I have never used them. Perhaps the answer lies with tasklets themselves.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easy -- just use a set:

```
futures = set(futures)
while futures:
    f = ndb.Future.wait_any(futures)
    futures.remove(f)
    yield f
```